# Migrate postgres data into cockroachDB

Tags: postgresql, migration, psql, cockroachdb

I'm trying to migrate all my data from Postgres (13) into CocroachDB.

I found this: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/migrate-from-postgres.html
I dumped data, then try to import using:

```sql
IMPORT PGDUMP 'nodelocal://self/do.sql' WITH ignore_unsupported_statements;
```

But... it doesn't work due to lack of sequence.

```
ERROR: referenced table "XXXXX_id_seq" not found in tables being imported (XXXXX_id_seq,XXXXX_id_seq,XXXXX_id_seq)
```

So I tried to export data w-o sequences.

```sh
pg_dump -U postgres --exclude-table=.*_id__seq > /tmp/dump.sql
```

And get again:

```
ERROR: referenced table "XXXXX_id_seq" not found in tables being imported (XXXXX_id_seq,XXXXX_id_seq,XXXXX_id_seq)
```

I can do it manually or just recreate all data from my app, but I really want to know how to do it on DB level using commands.

[Import Postgres dump into a table with CockroachDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333066/import-postgres-dump-into-a-table-with-cockroachdb) Here is only advise to remove all non-copy and non-create lines. It will take ages, many statemets are multiline.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPORT PGDUMP` Supports sequence creation, so I wonder if this error is occurring because of an inability to resolve a foreign key reference (i.e. crdb is attempting to import a table that references a sequence in another table that was ignored by IMPORT). Does the error go away if you include the `skip_foreign_keys` option? See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/migrate-from-postgres.html#skip-foreign-keys